# How does this backreference condition in a PHP regex work?

Tags: php, regex

My requirement is as follows:

1. If a string contains the word "cat", "cat" must be matched.
2. However, if the word "cat" is preceded by the word "dog", then "cat" must also be succeeded by "dog" and all 3 words must be matched.
3. This means that the string "dog cat" must not be matched, since the 2nd "dog" isn't present.

Accordingly, I have written the following regex in PHP. It contains a backreference condition:

```
      $ptn = '@' .                    // PHP delimiter
             '(dog\s*)?' .            // dog
             'cat\s*' .               // cat
             '(?(1)dog)' .            // backreference cond
             '@';                     // PHP delimiter
```

The regex meets requirement 1:

```
     $str1b = 'cat';
     preg_match($ptn, $str1b, $matches);
     print_r($matches);
```

The O/P is:

> Array ( [0] => cat )

The regex also meets requirement 2:

```
     $str1a = 'dog cat dog';
     preg_match($ptn, $str1a, $matches);
     print_r($matches);
```

The O/P is:

> Array ( [0] => dog cat dog [1] => dog )

However, I'd like to ask why the array contains 2 elements? Is it because the regex has 2 consuming sub-expressions?

Now about requirement 3. The following data tests it:

```
      $str1c = 'dog cat';
      preg_match($ptn, $str1c, $matches);
      print_r($matches);
```

The O/P here is:

> Array ( [0] => cat )

Here, I'd like to ask:

1. Why is "cat" matched? Since it is preceded by "dog", it should have been succeeded by "dog" too, which would have resulted in a match; else no match should have occurred.
2. Is this how the regex is supposed to work?
3. How can I achieve my 3 requirements?

Here's the [code](https://replit.com/@SMSteven/Backreference-Conditions-dog-cat-dog#index.php).

I am considering a solution only in PHP.

Comment: Do you mean like this? `\b(?:dog cat dog|(?:dog cat|cat dog)(*SKIP)(*F)|cat)\b` https://regex101.com/r/WIZfvp/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the 2 matches as you are using a capture group.

With the pattern that you tried `(dog\s*)?cat\s*(?(1)dog)` you get a match for `cat` in `dog cat`

This is because the pattern optionally matches dog. **If** there is dog, it is captured and then tries to match cat.

Then in the if clause is states: if we have group 1 present, match dog. What happens is that if there is no match in **group 1**, it can still match cat as the capture group 1 is optional.

So in `dog cat` it eventually can not match dog, but the following cat it can match when the attempt starts at cat.

---

If you want to match all 3 words `dog cat dog` or only a single `cat` and you don't want to match `dog cat` you might use

```
\b(?:dog cat dog|dog cat\b(*SKIP)(*F)|cat)\b
```

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial match
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `dog cat dog` Match literally
  - `|` Or
  - `dog cat\b(*SKIP)(*F)` In case of `dog cat` skip the match
  - `|` Or
  - `cat` Math only cat
- `)` Close non capture group
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/izL2mv/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/Q3bc5)

For example

```
$strings = [
    "cat",
    "dog cat dog",
    "dog cat",
    "cat dog",
    "this cat cat is a test dog cat dog cat"
];
$pattern = "/\b(?:dog cat dog|dog cat\b(*SKIP)(*F)|cat)\b/";
foreach ($strings as $str) {
    preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches);
    print_r($matches[0]);
}
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => cat
)
Array
(
    [0] => dog cat dog
)
Array
(
)
Array
(
    [0] => cat
)
Array
(
    [0] => cat
    [1] => cat
    [2] => dog cat dog
    [3] => cat
)
```

---

An alternative approach using a capture group could be matching what you want to avoid, and capture what you want to keep. For matching spaces, you could use `\s` but note that it could also match a newline.

```
\bdog cat\b(?! dog\b)|\b(dog cat dog|cat)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8LY9Hn/1)

If a quantifier is available in a lookbehind assertion, you might also use

```
\bdog cat dog\b|(?<!dog *)\bcat\b|cat(?= *dog\b)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/klv40X/1)

Comment: Yes, your regex works. I was just wondering why the regex I used doesn't. It matched "dog cat" when the back-reference condition states it shouldn't.

Comment: @SSteven With the pattern that you tried`(dog\s*)?cat\s*(?(1)dog)` you get a match for `cat` in `dog cat` This is because the pattern optionally matches `dog` If there is `dog` it tries to match `cat`. Then in the if clause is states: if we have group 1 present, match dog. What happens is that if there is no `dog` in group 1, it can still match `cat` as the capture group 1 is optional. So in `dog cat` it eventually can not match dog, but the next `cat` it can match when the attempt starts with `cat`.

Comment: @SSteven I have added an explanation to the answer.

Comment: OK, I see your point. There are 2 points about your solution: (a) It uses 2 or clauses (alternations) (b) The (*SKIP) and (*F) verbs are supported only by some implementations. On other implementations, how can the objective be achieved?

Comment: @SSteven In engines that do not support SKIP FAIL, you might use an approach using capture groups. Match, what you want to avoid, and capture what you want to keep. `\bdog cat\b(?! dog)|\b(dog cat dog|cat)\b` https://regex101.com/r/ibLYsR/1/

Comment: ++ for use of `(SKIP)(*F) but should it really match last `cat` in `this cat cat is a test dog cat dog cat` ?

Comment: @anubhava I assumed so, I also added an example of that in the regex demo to match the last cat in `cat dog cat dog cat dog` so that `cat dog cat` has the precedence.

Comment: Yes but last `cat` is also preceded by `dog` and not followed by a `dog`

Comment: @anubhava I think it would match that cat as in the first requirement there is `If a string contains the word "cat", "cat" must be matched.` You can always post an answer, I am a fan of your brilliant solutions :-)

Comment: @Thefourthbird, Your solution for implementations that don't support SKIP FAIL [doesn't work](https://replit.com/@SMSteven/dog-cat-dog-the-fourth-bird). It matches "dog cat".

Comment: @SSteven Is works, only you should take group 1 instead of the full match. The full match is what you don't want, and group 1 is what you do want.

Comment: @Thefourthbird, please test your solution on ideone with "dog cat".

Comment: @SSteven In the demo you can see that `dog cat` is not captured in group 1 https://ideone.com/PDTpaQ

Comment: @Thefourthbird, Yes I see it. You're right.

Answer (score 2):

> However, if the word "cat" is preceded by the word "dog", then "cat" must also be succeeded by "dog" and all 3 words must be matched

[TheFourthBird has a good answer using PCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67179762/548225)

Based on my interpretation this regex may also work for you:

```sh
\b(?:dog cat dog|(?<!\bdog )cat)\b
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `\b`: Word boundary
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `dog cat dog`: Match `dog cat dog`
  - `|`:
  - `(?<!\bdog )cat`: Match `cat` if not preceded by word `dog` and a space
- `)`: End non-capture group
- `\b`: Word boundary

Comment: Always a pleasure ++

Comment: @anubhava, Your solution for "dog cat dog" [doesn't work](https://replit.com/@SMSteven/lookahead-condition-dog-cat-dog-Anubhava#index.php)

Comment: @anubhava, Please try the repl link that I already posted in my comment.

Comment: You're using `\b(?=dog cat dog|(?<!\bdog )cat)\b` in your demo which is not same as in my answer.

Comment: @anubhava, Yes, you're right. I am not familiar with the ?: syntax. I used ?= (lookahead) on the assumption that it is the same.

Comment: @anubhava, I have tried it now with your [?:](https://replit.com/@SMSteven/lookahead-condition-dog-cat-dog-Anubhava-unsubstituted). It works correctly.

Comment: `(?:...)` is a [non-capture group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html). Glad it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [solution that works with standard syntax](https://replit.com/@SMSteven/lookahead-condition-dog-cat-dog-WORKS#index.php).

It matches "dog cat dog" and "cat" but NOT "dog cat".

I am unable to post the regex here, since SO claims it isn't indented properly (though it is). Please check the link for the regex.