# Regex match no groups, 1st group OR 2nd group but not both. Something like 'NAND'

Tags: python, regex

I can't figure out how to write regex that matches these:

- `everyone hi`
- `hi everyone`
- `hi`

But not this:

- `everyone hi everyone`

The regex `(?:everyone )?hi(?: everyone)?` will match the latter as well (which is not what I want). How to make such a regex? Or is it just not possible? I couldn't do enough research because I couldn't express the problem in correct words. Sorry if I posted a duplicate

Comment: There was a question like this for PHP, it will work for you if you use PyPi regex module. Else, you need a "best trick ever", `\b(?:everyone hi everyone|(hi everyone|(?:everyone )?hi))\b` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/TAzNfk/1))

Comment: You may try: `^(?:everyone(?: +hi)?|hi(?: +everyone)?)$`

Comment: @anubhava yep that works in fact, writing out the both parts. that can be an answer. but It would be nice if there was a bit better solution though

Comment: Here is the [PHP solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67179762/3832970) I  mentioned. It seems the requirements are a bit different though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a brute force alternation way to get this done:

```sh
^(?:everyone +hi|hi(?: +everyone)?)$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Lr5sev/1/)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?:`: Start a non-capture group

  - `everyone`: Match `everyone`:
  - `+hi`: Match 1+ spaces followed by `hi`
  - `|`: OR
  - `hi`: Match `hi`:
- `(?: +everyone)?`: Optionally match 1+ spaces followed by `everyone`
- `)`: End non-capture group
- `$`: End

Answer (score 3):

You could explicitly make a regex for each case (the first will capture two), utilizing beginning and end of line tokens

`(^hi( everyone)?$)`
`(^everyone hi$)`

Answer (score 1):

If you need to match these texts in a larger text, you can use

```py
\b(?:everyone hi(?! everyone)|(?<!everyone )hi(?: everyone)?)\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9MRjxG/1).

*Details*

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `everyone hi(?! everyone)` - `everyone hi` not followed by a space and `everyone`
  - `|` - or
  - `(?<!everyone )hi(?: everyone)?` - `hi` (not immediately preceded with `everyone` and a space) and an optional space+`everyone`
- `)` - end of the non-capturing group
- `\b` - a word boundary

With [PyPi regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/), you can have a more robust regex:

```
\beveryone hi everyone\b(*SKIP)(*F)|\b(?:(?:everyone\s+)?hi(?:\s+everyone)?)\b
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9MRjxG/2) and [this Python demo](https://tio.run/##bY4xC8IwEIX3/oojU66Ki1tBCg5CcRFcs1iM5qBeSnpKCv73mCItDsIN73vvcbx@FOd5mxI9eh8Egr3bWIiNAjtQ9mXD6NmCI8OOYOYJDO@fAuwFxNFQ/VSXmipCzG@CMu2/2LS6PB@bE@rygO9MdZVvSYcV1o6yk9VsYo2mVUUfiEV/x25uxNdL1@kQ1zANR8CUPg):

```py
import regex
text = "everyone hi\nhi everyone\nhi\nBut not this:everyone hi everyone"
rx = r"\beveryone hi everyone\b(*SKIP)(*F)|\b(?:(?:everyone\s+)?hi(?:\s+everyone)?)\b"
print( regex.findall(rx, text) )
## => ['everyone hi', 'hi everyone', 'hi']
```

Comment: That looks familiar :-) very nice ++